# Is the server running locally - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
tameen@tameen-HP:~/Downloads/$ sudo -u postgres 
tameen@tameen-HP:~/Downloads/$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for tameen: 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"?

tameen@tameen-HP:~/Downloads/$ netstat -an | more
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

if its listening the port `5432` and by using `export PGPORT=5432` its not working . How to solve this problem?

---

```
tameen@tameen-HP:~/Downloads$ sudo su postgres 
postgres@tameen-HP:/home/tameen/Downloads$ createdb template_postgis
could not change directory to "/home/tameen/Downloads": Permission denied
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide the port and host via `-p`/`-h` options:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1

createdb -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1 template_postgis
```

Comment: okay - see i am using postgresql 9.4 version - and django gives me this exception `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "geodjango". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?`

Comment: Did you follow "Installing PostGIS" instruction? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/

Comment: okay i am using django 1.5 old version for an old project to run it and to know its functionality - should i remove Postgresql - 9.4  and install 2.1 or above version - yes i follow this but i installed 9.4 -

Comment: Is 9.4 not a spatial?

Comment: `createdb` has the same `-p`/`-h` options as the `psql` command.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess you're using a PostgreSQL `psql` client and `libpq` compiled with a default `unix_socket_directories` of `/var/run/postgresql` but your server is compiled with `/tmp` as the default.

This is common when you have PostgreSQL installed from your distro's packages and also installed by some other means.

Use `psql -h /tmp/` to specify the unix socket directory, rather than switching to tcp/ip as @catavaran suggests.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the unix socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433` your client tries to connect to unix socket for a server running on port **5433**. According to your `netstat` output, your server is running on port **5432**.

I would suggest:

1. Stop the server
2. Delete all leftover socket files in `/var/run/postgresql/`
3. start the server again